# save file in db with unique name or id with asp classic

Tags: asp-classic

I'm new to asp my code is working absolutely fine, but  i am facing two problems although these problems are not affecting the application. I just want to make good functionality to the application logically.

When i upload excel file, if file with the same name it's already present, i overwrite it;  if i manually change file name then file is saved with new name.

What i want to do is:

1. save this new file with unique name or new name, i don’t know how to do this.
2. save this file in the db with the login user information (for future reference)

i hope my problems will be solved.  many thanks

[this is the url from which I got help..](http://shotdev.com/asp/asp-excel/asp-upload-excel-import-to-database/)

### CODE

upload_excel.asp

```
< form action="upload_excel_process.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="frmMain" onSubmit="return checkData();" >
<input name="file1" type="file"> <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
< %mem_id=session("mem_id")%>
< input type="hidden" name="client_id"  value="<%=mem_id%>">
< /form>
```

upload_excel_process.asp

```
<%client_id=session("mem_id")%>
<% 
Dim xlApp,xlBook,xlSheet1,xlSheet2,OpenFile,i
Dim Conn,strSQL,client_id,objExec
Dim mySmartUpload
Dim sFileName

Set mySmartUpload = Server.CreateObject("aspSmartUpload.SmartUpload")

mySmartUpload.Upload

sFileName = mySmartUpload.Files("file1").FileName

If sFileName <> "" Then

    mySmartUpload.Files("file1").SaveAs(Server.MapPath("excel/"&sFileName))

    OpenFile = "excel/"&sFileName

    Set xlApp = Server.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath(OpenFile))
    Set xlSheet1 = xlBook.Worksheets(1) 

    Set Conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    Conn.Open "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("../db/database.mdb"),"" , ""
    For  i = 2 To 5  
        If Trim(xlSheet1.Cells.Item(i,1)) <> "" Then  
            strSQL = ""  <br>
            strSQL = strSQL &"INSERT INTO add_contacts "
            strSQL = strSQL &"(client_id,name_receiver,contact_person_receiver,street_receiver,city_receiver, tel_receiver,fax_receiver,country_receiver,zip_code_receiver) "

            > i have added fields to the db for file (file_name and file_id)

            strSQL = strSQL &"VALUES " 
            strSQL = strSQL &"('"&client_id&"', '"&xlSheet1.Cells.Item(i,1)&"','"&xlSheet1.Cells.Item(i,2)&"','"&xlSheet1.Cells.Item(i,3)  &"'"  
            strSQL = strSQL &",'"&xlSheet1.Cells.Item(i,4)&"','"&xlSheet1.Cells.Item(i,5)&"','"&xlSheet1.  Cells.Item(i,6)&"','"&xlSheet1.Cells.Item(i,7)&"','"&xlSheet1.Cells.Item(i,8)&"')"

            Set objExec = Conn.Execute(strSQL)
            Set objExec = Nothing
        End IF 
    Next

    xlApp.Application.Quit

    Conn.Close()
    Set Conn = Nothing
    Set xlSheet1 = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End If

Set mySmartUpload = Nothing
%>
```

Comment: Would you mind to reformat your post? It is very hard to read and understand your text.

Comment: i suggest you to improve your redaction when you ask something here

Comment: Thanks Rafael vor formating this post. I wasn't able to edit it (whatever I couldn't).

Answer (score 0):

**Cheking of existens**

If you want to check if a filename does aleready exists, you have to use the method `FileExists` from standard `FilesystemObject` (for more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t(v=VS.85).aspx ).

So what do have to do?

```
If sFileName <> "" Then

 Dim fullFilePath = Server.MapPath("excel/"&sFileName)

 Dim fso
 Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 If (fso.FileExists(filespec)) Then
    //Rem Whatever you want to do here
 End If

 mySmartUpload.Files("file1").SaveAs(fullFilePath) 

 and so far...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to save the file with filename as unique to avoid the overwrite.

The best approach is to check before saving if the file exist in the destination directory or not. If it exists change the file name by appending some unique id like timestamp.

To save the file use *saveas* method.

```
strFileName = PMSmartUpload.Files.Item(1).FileName
strFilePath = strFileDirectory & "\" & strFileName

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If (fso.FileExists(strFilePath)) Then
        ''rename suffix for file
        strDateExt = cstr(month(Date)) +cstr(day(Date))+cstr(year(Date)) +cstr(Hour(Now)) +cstr(Minute(Now)) +cstr(Second(Now))
        strFileExtension =fso.GetExtensionName(strFileName) 
        strFileBaseName = fso.GetBaseName(strFileName)       
        strFileName = strFileBaseName+"_"+ strDateExt +"."+strFileExtension
    End If 
    'response.write strFileDirectory&"\"&strFileName
    PMSmartUpload.Files.Item(1).saveas strFileDirectory&"\"&strFileName
```

In short the saveas method will save the posted file with specified name(full path)